# How to make sticky header with out plugin in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, sticky

I want to make a sticky header without a plugin. when mouse scrolling then header padding decreases. normally show expand header when scrolling then decreases padding.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do this by adding/removing a class with JavaScript. You then use CSS to change the padding/size when this new class is added to your element. Here I add the "activated" class to a nav element with ID "ScrollNav" after user scrolls 100px down, then remove it if they scroll up again.

**JS**

```
window.onscroll = function() {scrollHeader()};

function scrollHeader() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 100 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 100) {
    document.getElementById("ScrollNav").className = "activated";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("ScrollNav").className = "";
  }
}
```

**CSS**

```
#ScrollNav {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  padding:60px 20px;
  transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

#ScrollNav.activated {
  padding:20px;
  transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

**Notes:**

1. There are better ways of adding/removing the class names (this method will kill any other class names you apply to your element) but it's simple, so it might be a good fit.
2. Change the number in here `document.body.scrollTop > 100 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 100` to change when the effect starts: bigger number means the function is called further down the page; lower number calls it sooner.

Here's a little pen to see it working: https://codepen.io/captain_matt/pen/KKWmQWL